# Mechanisms of a mobile robot

Tags: robotics

what is the need of the upper wheels in the figure shown?[image]

Comment: You mean the 4 large sprockets? Those give the track angle and height that let it climb obstacles. Haven't you ever seen a tank? Without them, the track would have similar climbing ability to a wheel the same diameter as one of the tiny sprockets.

Answer (score 1):

The function of various wheels are as shown:

[image: function]

The belt angle is required for movement in uneven terrain (consider stair climbing or climbing over rocks and pits).